# Replacing NA with lookup value on two columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that includes date, time of day, and measurement value over a number of days.

Some of the measurements are NA. I'd like to replace these with an imputed value.

To solve this, I created a second dataframe to hold the imputed value:

```
meanMeasurementByTimeAndDayOfWeek <- 
  ddply(activityData, c('timeofday', 'dayOfWeek'), 
  summarize, avgMeasurement = mean(measurement, na.rm=TRUE))
```

(I think that's right.)

How do I replace the NA's in the measurement column of my activityData dataframe with the avgMeasurement value from the second dataframe based on the timeofday and dayOfWeek values?

Answer (score 3):

We could do this without creating a new dataset.  Using `dplyr`, we group by 'timeofday', 'dayOfWeek', and `replace` the NA elements (`which(is.na(measurement))`) in 'measurement' by the `mean` value.

```
library(dplyr)
a <- activityData %>%
       group_by(timeofday, dayOfWeek) %>%
       mutate(Mean= mean(measurement, na.rm=TRUE), 
               measurement= replace(measurement, 
                  which(is.na(measurement)), first(Mean))) %>%
       select(-Mean)
```

Or we use `ifelse`, which will be more direct

```
 a1 <- activityData %>%
          group_by(timeofday, dayOfWeek) %>%
          mutate(measurement= ifelse(is.na(measurement),
            mean(measurement, na.rm=TRUE), as.numeric(measurement)))
```

Or we use the `na.aggregate` from `library(zoo)` in the `mutate` call.

```
library(zoo)
b <- activityData %>%
      group_by(timeofday, dayOfWeek) %>%
      mutate(measurement= na.aggregate(measurement))

identical(a$measurement, b$measurement)
#[1] TRUE
identical(a1$measurement, b$measurement)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or a similar option using `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(activityData)`), grouped by the variable, we assign (`:=`) measurement as the `na.aggregate` of 'measurement'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(activityData)[, measurement := na.aggregate(measurement) ,
               by = .(timeofday, dayOfWeek)]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
activityData <- data.frame(timeofday= sample(1:24, 100, replace=TRUE), 
     dayOfWeek=sample(1:7, 100, replace=TRUE),
     measurement= sample(c(NA, 1:5), 100, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: akrun, thank you so much for the time you took providing such a detailed answer. I'm new enough to R that I don't fully understand your code, but when I tried a few of these solutions, the NA's were all replaced with the same value independent of timeofday and dayOfWeek. I need to replace each NA with the mean of the timeofday and dayOfWeek of that particular row, and that's not what I'm finding when I run your code. I'll keep working on this and see if I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Nevo Could you update your post with a small example and expected output.  Based on the example I created, it seems to be working.